# Rewrite GET variables using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I wanted to rewrite my GET variables from this:

```
www.domain.com/service/index.php?url=http://www.google.com
```

to

```
www.domain.com/service/http://www.google.com
```

So, I used the following .htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rule is messing up the GET request and making the url from

```
http://www.google.com
to
http:/www.google.com
```

which is not working for me.

After Rewrite, I want the url in the GET to be as it is for eg

```
http://www.google.com
```

should be `http://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code in /service/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?url=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NC,NE,L,R]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,NE,L]
```

Comment: You'd also have to use `B` or `NE` flags, so that `/` and `:` are not converted/escaped.

Comment: I get this - `The requested URL /service/http://www.google.com was not found on this server.`

Comment: Is your htaccess inside root or sub folder?

Comment: It is inside a sub-folder named `service`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95132/discussion-between-maven-maverick-and-starkeen).

Comment: You can now visit http://domain.com/service/index.php?url=http://google.com or http://domain.com/service/http://google.com both are pointing to SEF

Comment: Again the same problem, `http://www.google.com becomes http:/www.google.com`. I just want the 2 slashes of http:`//` to be intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in `/service/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /service/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?url=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NE,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)
RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=%1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)` **is important here** to allow for `http://www.google.com` not becoming `http:/www.google.com` otherwise `mod_rewrite` strips multiple `/`s into a single `/` in `RewriteRule`.